# When marshalling, why does JAXB not call getter method for a required attribute with a fixed value?

Tags: binding, jaxb, marshalling, fixed, required

I have an attribute:

The associated getter method in the generated JAXB object is like this:

```
public String getUnits(){
    if(units == null) return "metric";
    else return units;
}
```

getUnits() is not being called by JAXB Marshaller when marshalling and the value is not being set.
Why would this not be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**schema.xsd**

Below is a simplified version of the XML schema that you used to generate your Java classes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <attribute name="units" fixed="metric"/>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**Root**

This will result in a class like the following to be generated.  Since `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` is specified your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will get the value form the field instead of accessing the `getUnits()` method.

```java
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "units")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String units;


    public String getUnits() {
        if (units == null) {
            return "metric";
        } else {
            return units;
        }
    }

    public void setUnits(String value) {
        this.units = value;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html